# Generated $\sigma$ - algebra example

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $\Omega = \mathbb{Z}$.

Consider $E_1 := \big\{\{2n|n \in \mathbb{Z}\}\big\}$ and $E_2 := \big\{\{2n\} | n \in \mathbb{Z}\big\}$.

Find the generated $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma$($E_1$) and $\sigma$($E_2$).

So this solution is from my teacher:

$$\sigma(E_1) = \{ \emptyset, E_1, E_1^c, \Omega \} = \big\{ \emptyset, \{2n|n \in \mathbb{Z}\}, \{2n+1|n \in \mathbb{Z}\}, \mathbb{Z} \big\}.$$

$$\sigma(E_2) = \big\{ \mathcal{P}(E_2),  \{2n+1|n \in \mathbb{Z}\}, ( \{2n+1|n \in \mathbb{Z}\} \cup C ) | C \in \mathcal{P}(E_2) \}$$
Remark: $\mathcal{P}$ is the power set.

So is this really correct?

To me $\sigma(E_1)$ is only correct if we would have $E_1 = \{2n|n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ not $\big\{\{2n|n \in \mathbb{Z}\}\big\}$. And for $\sigma(E_2)$ I would say that we have $\big\{ C, \{2n+1|n \in \mathbb{Z}\}, ( \{2n+1|n \in \mathbb{Z}\} \cup C ) | C \in \mathcal{P}(E_2)\}$.

Comment: You're right... actually I would say that if $E_1$ is the set of even integers, then $\{\emptyset,E_1,E_1^c,\Omega\}$ is $\sigma(\{E_1\})$.

Comment: I suggest you change the question back so that my answer makes sense with what is written. You can put a summary of the solution at the end if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your objection to the second one is correct. The correct answer looks something like

$$ \sigma(E_2) = \mathcal{P}(\{2n \mid n \in \mathbb Z\}) \cup \{ \{2n + 1 \mid n \in \mathbb Z \} \cup C \mid C \in \mathcal{P}(\{2n \mid n \in \mathbb Z\}) \}. $$

There's no need to include $\{2n + 1 \mid n \in \mathbb Z \}$ seperately because we can simply take $C = \varnothing$. And, unless I'm missing something, we require $\mathcal{P}(\{2n \mid n \in \mathbb Z\})$ instead of  $\mathcal{P}(E_2)$ because the latter is neither a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ nor a collection of subsets of $\mathbb Z$.

The first one is wrong but I wouldn't say it's for the reason you mention.  Note that the set $E_1$ has to be a collection of subsets of $\mathbb Z$. I.e. a subset of $\mathcal P(\mathbb Z)$. In this case the subset is $E_1 = \{A\}$ where $A$ is the set of even integers. On the other hand, $A$ is not a collection of subsets of $\mathbb Z$ so if we set $E_1 = A$ then $\sigma(E_1)$ isn't defined (unless you define it to mean $\sigma(\{A\})$). We always have

$$ \sigma(\{A\}) = \{\varnothing, A, A^c, \Omega\}.$$

The mistake here is that

$$ \sigma(E_1) \ne \{\varnothing, E_1, E_1^c, \Omega\} $$

because again $E_1 \not\subseteq \mathbb Z$.

Comment: So the first one was also wrong... $E_1$ was both the set of even integers and the singleton with that set as only element.

Comment: Well, just this was wrong: $\sigma(E_1) = \{\emptyset, E_1, E_1^c, \Omega \}$.

Comment: Thank you Trevor Gunn and Alejandro Nasif Salum for your help. I edited my question. Hope that this solution is now the correct one. ! :)